# ROS serial communication with microcontroller

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am newbie to ROS and I want to send Odometry data from P89V51RD2 controller to ROS. I found [link: text](http://answers.ros.org/question/10114/how-can-ros-communicate-with-my-microcontroller) , but I am not able to run it .. Can someone help out with same code , right from creating packages and meeting dependencies..
Thanks..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30161/ros-serial-communication-with-microcontroller/) by [anonymous2029](https://answers.ros.org/users/2029/anonymous2029/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-03-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous2029](https://answers.ros.org/users/2029/anonymous2029/) on 2012-03-21**:
I want to send the 'x' 'y' 'z' coordinates as (char) from uC to ROS ..

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-03-21**:
I presume you're referring to http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial. Could you provide some background into what problems you're having?

**Comment by [anonymous2029](https://answers.ros.org/users/2029/anonymous2029/) on 2012-03-21**:
Hmm. I am referring to the code in the link .. I just found out that it is working, but it is taking 30 seconds or more to receive data.. it takes data for some time  and after few seconds, it publishes all .. is it possible to make it more nearer to real time.. should i change rcvBufSize..?

**Comment by [anonymous2029](https://answers.ros.org/users/2029/anonymous2029/) on 2012-03-21**:
When i set rcvBufSize to 1, i dont get any true response, it keeps on giving data = ' ' as output to rostopic echo uc0Response.. when i set rcvBufSize to 5 , I get response in group of 4 without loss of any data..but it take more than 20 seconds to show up on the screen..

**Comment by [anonymous2029](https://answers.ros.org/users/2029/anonymous2029/) on 2012-03-21**:
is it normal to get such slow data fetching and publishing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It isn't serial specific like [rosserial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial), but [rosbridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbridge) *may* also suit your needs (full disclosure, author of rosbridge here). Check out [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lo2diadVEG4) of using rosbridge with an Arduino (though the principles apply to any uController).

---

Originally posted by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) with karma: 461 on 2012-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-03-21**:
We tend to recommend rosserial with uCs with Arduino-like specs, and rosbridge for more capable ones (ARM, for instance).

**Comment by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) on 2012-03-21**:
Good point. I guess I tend to think the opposite because with less capable uCs I use a machine side adapter program and a light custom protocol. I hate having any sort of real protocol implementation on the uC *unless* it's beefy. The exception is rosserial on Arduino, because of the good support.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*I also apologize for commenting as an answer (however, 300 characters without advanced formatting was not likely going to cut it for a response).*

First off, let me say that I understand that unix command hackery isn't everyone's cup of tea. A simple helper program, such as [this](http://pastebin.com/aaZ61eJL) Python equivalent to my example one-liner does the same job just as well. As with the unix command, you may need to change the serial device name.

One the other hand, if you do want to get this working from the command line...

I assume you intentionally changed /dev/ttyACM0 to /dev/ttyUSB0. However, you may still want to check your device name and suffix number. I also assume you intentionally changed the - to STDOUT. Those changes aside, I do see a few potential typos:

```
1,1 s/^./raw\r\n\r\n/
```

should read:

```
1,1 s/^.*/raw\r\n\r\n/
```

(i.e. it's missing a star)

```
s/([0-9])/
```

should read:

```
s/\([0-9]*\)/
```

(i.e. missing a star and some quoting backslashes)

and your:

```
"type":std_msgs\/Int64"
```

is missing a quote after the **:**, it should read:

```
"type":"std_msgs\/Int64"
```

finally (and this may be an intentional omission on your part) your orison is missing the final:

```
| nc localhost 9090
```

All that said, you can copy the exact orison (sans your device changes) from [this](http://pastebin.com/C918E6uH) pastebin, mentioned in the video.

---

Originally posted by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) with karma: 461 on 2012-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-03-22**:
Agree, the character limit in comments is really annoying

**Comment by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) on 2012-03-23**:
I also just realized that if you aren't logged in you don't see past the first five comments and aren't offered the textual "more" button. However, if you try to post a comment, the comments are revealed to you.

What is this? I don't even...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can always use cereal_port, a serial port library for ROS, you can find it in the serial_communication stack, it's very easy to use!

http://www.ros.org/wiki/serial_communication/

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) with karma: 591 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-03-22**:
Agree, cereal_port is a good library

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-01-09**:
Pardon this newbie, but http://wiki.ros.org/serial_communication doesn't seem to have support for Hydro yet, or am I confused about how the wiki presents information.  I see Electric and Fuerte, but no Hydro.  What is the best/easiest way to do serial communication from Hydro?  Thanks.